# there is no map $T^2\rightarrow T^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $T^2$ be torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$. For a matrix $A$ in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$,  $~f_A$ is induced map on $T^2$ by $A$. Let $A$ and $B$ be
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\ 1&1\end{array}\right),~~~B=A^2$$

I want to show there is no homeomorphism $h:T^2\rightarrow T^2$ such that $f_B\circ h=h\circ f_A$ .

My idea: I paid attention to the homology groups of $T^2$. But induced map on $H_*(T^2)$ by $f_A$ and $f_B$ is isomorphism, so I became to have no idea. Please give me some advice.

Comment: If such an $h$ exists, then $H_1(f_B)$ and $H_1(f_A)$ should have the same eigenvalues because $H_1(h)$ gives a similarity transformation (real coefficients). Do they?

Comment: I got it! The eigenvalues of $A$ is $\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and those of $B$ is $\frac{-7\pm 3\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so such a $h$ can't exist. Thank you for your idea:)

Comment: Your title as it is now makes a clearly false statement.